# how to go to next webpage web scraping

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am learning to **scrape** websites
How to go to next page until the last page and append data and save in csv

```
URL = "https://agmarknet.gov.in/SearchCmmMkt.aspx?Tx_Commodity=78&Tx_State=KK&Tx_District=0&Tx_Market=0&DateFrom=01-Jan-2015&DateTo=01-Feb-2021&Fr_Date=01-Jan-2015&To_Date=01-Feb-2021&Tx_Trend=0&Tx_CommodityHead=Tomato&Tx_StateHead=Karnataka&Tx_DistrictHead=--Select--&Tx_MarketHead=--Select--"

tables = pd.read_html(URL,attrs = {'class' : 'tableagmark_new'})
while True:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
    next_page_btn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class = 'pagination-next']/a")
    if len(next_page_btn) < 1:
        break
    else:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Next'))).click()
```

I Want data from the above table link in csv format. I am able to get data from first table but unable to automate it to go to next page and append data from next tables.

Comment: Why do you need this? There is an `Export to Excel` button on the site that exports all data to a 50mb excel file

Comment: Ok, I've posted an answer that will let you load the html into pandas in one line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following `xpath` to click on the next page.

```
next_page_btn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[contains(@src,'Next')]")
if len(next_page_btn) < 1:
     break
 else:
     WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@src,'Next')]"))).click()
```

Comment: Now I can go to next page but I also want to append the data from the table and save in csv format.

Comment: @GHOSTRIDER : your initial problem gets resolved and you able to go to next page. I would appreciate if you post separate question for your new requirement. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I will try to do the next part.

Comment: @GHOSTRIDER : If you need any assistance please post another question with details other contributor will try to help you. Good day.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're also open to processing the exported `xls` file:
As you mentioned, the `xls` file is actually a html file. This means that you can read it into pandas with [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)

```
df = pd.read_html('Agmarknet_Price_Report.xls')
```

`read_html` produces a list of dataframes of all tables in the html file. Since there is only one table present in your data you can access the dataframe with `df[0]`.
`df[0].head()` will output:

|  | Sl no. | District Name | Market Name | Commodity | Variety | Grade | Min Price (Rs./Quintal) | Max Price (Rs./Quintal) | Modal Price (Rs./Quintal) | Price Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Hassan | Arasikere | Tomato | Tomato | FAQ | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 09 Dec 2020 |
| 1 | 2 | Hassan | Arasikere | Tomato | Tomato | FAQ | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 20 Nov 2020 |
| 2 | 3 | Hassan | Arasikere | Tomato | Tomato | FAQ | 750 | 750 | 750 | 07 Apr 2020 |
| 3 | 4 | Hassan | Arasikere | Tomato | Tomato | FAQ | 1500 | 1500 | 1500 | 12 Mar 2020 |
| 4 | 5 | Hassan | Arasikere | Tomato | Tomato | FAQ | 1500 | 1500 | 1500 | 06 Mar 2020 |

You can then save the dataframe to csv: `df[0].to_csv('filename.csv')`. This will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked in converting the data into csv.